# Fluentvalidator multistep form validate per step

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, fluentvalidation

I have a MVC application with a multistep form (no I can not use javascript) consisting of multiple actions. I have a form model with fluentvalidation setup. However it validates all validations for each step. I would like it to validate only the properties belonging to the current step. Is there a way to tell fluent validator to only validate certain properties?

Comment: You should have a separate view model for each step containing only the properties that have sense for this step. It is also possible to perform conditional validation but you will have to tell us much more about how you are performing this wizard. How your models, controllers and views look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a way, [RuleSet](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2011/02/03/fluentvalidation-v3-rulesets/), For each step declare a different RuleSet.